# Does creation/update of an EmailMessage record ever send an actual email?

Tags: email, soap-api, singleemailmessage, data-migration

I suspect the answer is no, that one would need to use an unrelated call such as sendEmail() or something like that to actually send a message.

That said, I'm in the process of doing a data migration and want to ensure there are no possibilities of loading records into the EmailMessage object and having it send out emails (I'm changing the status value of the EmailMessage record for an ordering reasons from Draft to Sent which is why I'm wanting to confirm).  While I tested it and was unable to trigger any actual email sends, can someone confirm my understanding?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think updating EmailMessage shouldn't send email. To send an email, you need to create another instance of email with status as sent. Go through the given link answering a similar kinda question: [How to send a draft EmailMessage linked to a case](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/30183/how-to-send-a-draft-emailmessage-linked-to-a-case)